# increase vertical distance between nodes with forest

Tags: forest

I have the following tree and want to increase the vertical space between the nodes. Is there a straightforward way to do this?

```
\documentclass{article}                          


\usepackage{forest}
\forestset{
sn edges/.style={for tree={parent anchor=south, child anchor=north,align=center,base=bottom,where n children=0{tier=word}{}}}, 
background tree/.style={for tree={text opacity=0.2,draw opacity=0.2,edge={draw opacity=0.2}}}
}



\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
sn edges
[D-Struktur,edge label={node[midway,right]{move $\alpha$}} 
  [S-Struktur
        [Tilgungsregeln{,}\\Filter{,} phonol. Regeln
                [Phonetische\\Form (PF)]]
        [Regeln des anaphorischen Bezugs{,}\\der Quantifizierung und der Kontrolle
                [Logische\\Form (LF)]]]]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For example:

```
...
  [S-Struktur,l=3cm
...
```

Comment: OK. Thanks. I begin to understand this powerful package. I added: `for tree = {l=3cm}` to get all distances larger.

Comment: is there a way to do the same in the horizontal way?

Comment: I found somthing: could be the `s sep=XXXcm`